# timing a python program with threads

Tags: python, multithreading, time

I have the following block of code that is part of a larger program.  I am trying to get it to print the execution time once all of the threads are closed but can't seem to get it to work.  Any ideas?

```
import time
import csv
import threading 
import urllib.request


def openSP500file():
    SP500 = reader(open(r'C:\Users\test\Desktop\SP500.csv', 'r'), delimiter=',')
    for x in SP500:
        indStk = x[0]
        t1 = StockData(indStk)
        t1.start()

    if not t1.isAlive():
        print(time.clock()-start_time, 'seconds')
    else:
        pass

def main():
    openSP500file()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.clock()
    main()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Neither reader nor StockData is defined. Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: This is part of a larger program.  Reader is referring to csv.reader and StockData is referring to my stock data class.  The code runs, I just can't get it to print the execution time because of the threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't waiting for all the threads to finish (only the last one created). Perhaps something like this in your thread-spawning loop?

```
threads = []
for x in SP500:
    t1 = StockData(x[0])
    t1.start()
    threads.append(t1)
for t in threads:
    t.join()
... print running time
```

Comment: When I tried this it prints the time that each thread completes.  I would just want the time that the last one completes, or even better, just the complete running time of the program.

Comment: The print statement lines up with the 'for' and not with 't.join'. Admittedly the ellipsis makes this hard to see